# How to write an elegant behaviors in Model of Yii2?

Tags: php, web, yii2

When I write model's method `behaviors`. There are some behaviors defined in the returned value. Look at the following code:

```
'timestamp' => [
    'class' => 'yii\behaviors\TimestampBehavior',
    'attributes' => [
        ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_INSERT => ['submitTime'],
    ],
```

it means that the attribute `submitTime` will generate automatically. I want to judge whether the attribute `submitTime` is null. it will generate when it is null. I achieve like this:

```
'value' => function ($event) {
    if ($this->submitTime) {
        return $this->submitTime;
    }
    return time();
},
```

Is there an elegant way to achieve my idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert it to a 1-liner:

```
'value' => function ($event) {
    return $this->submitTime ?: time();
},
```

Comment: I know this syntax. have some other ways that do not use the attribute `value`

Comment: I don't understand what you actually want.

Comment: ;(, I got no idea about this.